# how to make changes in myveinsapp using demomessageapp

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, sumo

omnet++ veins sumo simulators for IOV project
hey i am working in omnet sumo veins and i m trying to understand what is happening in the veins example. it will be very helpful if you how to understand the code. and if you have your code please share. thank you in advance.
just run a veins example and trying to log the communication happening between cars and rsus and other devices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find various project templates in Vanet using OMNeT++, SUMO and Veins:
[Projects](https://github.com/dnatividade/Vanet-Projects)
[Issues](https://github.com/dnatividade/VEINS-tutorials/issues)